# Java spring-boot login example code with thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Recently I have found an example of simple registration and login in spring boot.
Code can be found here: https://github.com/sambaf/NHSystem

However I cannot use thymeleaf inside my project and I need functionality from this project - my question is:
How the hell is login processed inside code? If I remove thymeleaf dependency in maven login don't work. If we will look inside login controller:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {


@GetMapping("/")
public String showIndexPage() {

    return "index";  
}

@GetMapping("/login") 
public String showLoginForm() {

    return "views/loginForm";  
}

 }
```

there is no `password&login` validation! How does this work? I just wanted to do this project without using `thymeleaf`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use any Views technology instead of thymeleaf to generate HTML forms:

1. JSP
2. JSTL
3. Velocity
4. XSLT
5. JSF
6. Struts
7. Tapestry

and so on

See [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/index.html) and [examples](https://spring.io/guides)

**P.S.** Also you can generate HTML form in Java code using [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) (see [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-servlet)), but it is quite old and a strange ways to generate html form, and I can't recommend it.

Comment: I put an HTML form inside .jsp file and result is 403 Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.

Answer (score 1):

You can check code inside of the [SecurityConfig](https://github.com/sambaf/NHSystem/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sambasoft/config/SecurityConfig.java)

in these lines he/she implemented login logic:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select email as principal, password as credentails, true from user where email=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_email as principal, role_name as role from user_roles where user_email=?")
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).rolePrefix("ROLE_");  

    }
```

And he/she implemented these lines for specifying submitted user credentials.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register", "/", "/about", "/login", "/css/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/profile").hasAnyRole("USER,ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/users","/addTask").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile").and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }
```

more specifically `.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()`

Finally lets get handling your issue. This is not related thymeleaf. You need to create login page that submitted to `/login`.

That login logic about [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security)

Comment: you can use .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/login").permitAll() if http method is POST

Comment: @gokhanbirincii Adding    <input type="hidden"
   name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
made that .jsp login page started to work. Question is why thymeleaf dont need this piece of code?

Comment: this situation about csrf. if you add `http.csrf()` in configure method, you must send csrf token while you sending `put, delete, post` requests.

Comment: @gokhanbirincii that means that thymeleaf removes/or add http.csrf automatically?

Comment: no, thymeleaf didn't neither add nor remove  csrf automatically.